# Why fused multiply add operation is not used?

Tags: c, riscv

I am using riscv-gcc to compile this simple C program.

```
int main()
{
    float a, b, c, d;
    a = 4.0;
    b = 3;
    c = 5.3;
    d = a*b + c;
    return 0;
}
```

I want riscv-gcc to generate floating point mulitply add (fma) instruction to compute d. But instead gcc generates a floating point multiply instruction and floating point add instruction.

Here is the assembly for program generated by risv-gcc:

```
main:
    addi    sp,sp,-32
    sd  s0,24(sp)
    addi    s0,sp,32
    lui a5,%hi(.LC0)
    flw fa5,%lo(.LC0)(a5)
    fsw fa5,-20(s0)
    lui a5,%hi(.LC1)
    flw fa5,%lo(.LC1)(a5)
    fsw fa5,-24(s0)
    lui a5,%hi(.LC2)
    flw fa5,%lo(.LC2)(a5)
    fsw fa5,-28(s0)
    flw fa4,-20(s0)
    flw fa5,-24(s0)
    fmul.s  fa5,fa4,fa5
    flw fa4,-28(s0)
    fadd.s  fa5,fa4,fa5
    fsw fa5,-32(s0)
    li  a5,0
    mv  a0,a5
    ld  s0,24(sp)
    addi    sp,sp,32
    jr  ra
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align  2
.LC0:
    .word   1082130432
    .align  2
.LC1:
    .word   1077936128
    .align  2
.LC2:
    .word   1084856730
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.2.0"
```

How can i force riscv-gcc to use fma instruction?

Comment: Q: How can i force riscv-gcc to use fma instruction?  A: In-line assembly?  Risc-V specific command line options are listed here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RISC-V-Options.html#RISC-V-Options

Comment: Your `main` method has no side effects but generates a bunch of output ... turn optimisations on?

Comment: @ta.speot.is Is `fmadd` useful in the implementation of `return 0;`? 

Comment: The quantity of loads/stores to the stack strongly suggests that you compiled at -O0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're compiling without optimisations.

```cpp
float fma(float a, float b, float c)
{
    return a*b + c;
}
```

With -O3:

```
fma(float, float, float):
        fmadd.s fa0,fa0,fa1,fa2
        ret
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried earlier using -O3 optimization but since I was not using variable d anywhere, riscv-gcc was not generating the instruction. Also, had to use volitile float.

Comment: *had to use volatile float* Well I didn't, so you might still be doing something weird there.